# select different values for column based on what table the row exists in

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have this query

```
define LAST_DATE_BEFORE = to_date('03112016','ddmmyyyy')

with 
table1 as (some result),
table2 as (some result),
select
  MS.PAID_TRANS_IND,
  MS.CURR_PRICE_PLAN_KEY,
  case
    when MS.SEGMENT_KEY in t1.SEGMENT_KEY
    then MS.PLAN_SEGMENT_KEY
    when MS.SEGMENT_KEY in t2.SEGMENT_KEY
      and MS.START_ALLOC_DATE = &LAST_DATE_BEFORE + 1
    then MS.SEGMENT_KEY
    else null
  end as SEGMENT_KEY
  from MO_SU MS, table1 t1, table2 t2
```

table 1 and 2 have different values from table MO_SU. Now I just check column values, but I want to check if the whole row can be found in t1/t2.

I thought this could work

```
when MS.* in t1.*
```

it doesn't.

What can I do?

Comment: I see a potential problem with your query.  You are doing a cross join between the three tables, which may not be what you intended.

Comment: Keeping aside the rest of your code, if I understand well, the issue is about checking if a row of a table exists in another table, with equal values in all the columns; if so, you have to specify all the columns in your condition

Comment: @Tim Yes, I don't want to join them, just compare rows.

Comment: As Tim said, check your joining, also the thing you want to do have to be spelled out so (MS.col1,MS.col2,MS.col3) in (t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3)

Comment: In addition to what Aleksej and Emil have said, don't forget to take care of null values when comparing your rows, since in Oracle, `null = null` will return null, not true (or false).

Comment: what was the downvote for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to reduce the question to checking if a given row of a table exists in another table, with equal values in all the columns, not using a JOIN but only the `IN`, you may need something like the following ( assuming `not null` values):

```
with
  tab1(colA, colB, colC) as ( select 'a', 'b', 'c' from dual union all
                              select 'A', 'B', 'C' from dual 
                            ),
  tab2(columnA, columnB, columnC) as (  select 'a', 'b', 'c' from dual)
select *
from tab1 
where (colA, colB, colC) in ( select columnA, columnB, columnC from tab2)
```

If the second table had exactly the columns you need to check, in the right order and with no other column, in theory you could even edit it into :

```
...
where (colA, colB, colC) in ( select * from tab2)
```

but I absolutely recommend **NOT** to use such an approach: it's always better to avoid things like `select *`.

Answer (score 0):

OK so if `table1` and `table2` contains records from `MO_SU` you can do such thing:

```
with
table1 as (select rowid r, s.* from MO_SU),
table2 as (select rowid r, s.* from MO_SU)
select what_you_need
from
MO_SU MS inner join (select * from table1 t1 union all select * from table2 t2) t on (MO_SU.rowid = t.r);
```

However I don't see deeper sense here. What code do because if you're using only data from `MO_SU` you could probably select it in `with`. `rowid` is unique identifier of row so if you attach `rowid` in CTEs you can the join on `rowid` to filter only data that is present in CTEs.